# Enterprise Architect API for Displaying Image Manager Dialog

Tags: c#, image, enterprise-architect

I am working on adding images to EA through forms  in enterprise architect C# add-ins.

Adding images from local file path is feasible. However, I am unable to find a way where user can add images that are already available in image manager through form.

Is there an EA API similar to Repository.InvokeConstructPicker("IncludedTypes=Package;")to invoke the Image Manager dialog . 
I also found tagged value Type=ImageRef which opens the image manager directly but I want to display image manager from windows form.

Kindly help.

Comment: I don't think so. Unless you know the secret sauce to invoke it using `Repository.CustomCommand`

Comment: Geert is right. You might send a feature request. Not dreaming of having a Sparx documentation for `CustomCommand`
... (argghh) http://www.sparxsystems.com/forums/smf/index.php?topic=29281.msg216788#msg216788